# center element directly below and in the middle of text

Tags: html, css

The problem I am trying to solve in my project:

I want to have the selected state of a link in my navbar be a small icon.

I want that icon to sit directly below and in the middle of the navbar link text.

I can't seem to figure it out.

I mimicked some of the css in the project below.

Essentially I am trying to get the text "trying ma best" centered in the middle of the parent "center the text below me relative".

All of our nav links sit inline, so I don't want to alter the a tag being inline.

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lk1uqs8/5/

here is the code in the fiddle:

```
<a href="#">
  center the text below me relative to me
  <div>
    trying ma best
  </div>
</a>

a {
  display: inline;
}

div {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
a {
  display: inline-flex; /* takes only the contents width; you can also use "flex" (100% width) */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks flex-items (children) vertically */
  align-items: center; /* centers them horizontally */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  center the text below me relative to me
  <div>
    trying ma best
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `relative` and `absolute` position to achieve the desired results.

```
a {
 display:inline;
 position:relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width:100%; /* instead of this you can use left:0; right:0 also */
  text-align:center;
}
```

```css
a {
  display:inline;
  position:relative;
  }

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  center the text below me relative to me
  <div>
    centere insdff
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: gave you an upvote because this is an awesome answer that totally works, ended up implementing the flexbox answer though

Comment: :) it is all about our need.

Answer (score 0):

not full proof but could be a good starting point. https://jsfiddle.net/p1er4t2p/

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
}

a:after {
  visibility:hidden;
  content:'center';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

a:hover::after{
  visibility:visible;
}


<a href="#">
  center the text below me relative to me
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following css

```
a {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
a div {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**PS:`div` inside `anchor` tag is not good method** [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: If he change the `div` text then this solution won't work.

Comment: yeah thats why i have commented margin-left should be half width of conent div

Comment: if he don't know that the div width then again it will be a problem. you can make it simple like in my answer.